# Check to see what two prime numbers are around a number from the user

Tags: java, primes

I am supposed to write a program that accepts a value from the user greater (than two of course) and print out the two prim numbers closest to it. I am supposed to use a method to simplify the process.
For example, if the user inputted 24 the two numbers are 23 and 29.
I am just confused about the math behind it. How would I go about doing this? I just want somebody to put me on the right track. Thanks a ton

Comment: The two primes closest, or the two primes around it?  E.g. if given 58 do you expect 59 and 61 (the primes with minimal distance from 58), or 53 and 59 (prev_prime(58) and next_prime(58)).  What do you expect when given a prime as input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did sthg like this;
I write two for loop to scan both side, and a prime method to find prime numbers.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int minPrime = 0;
        int maxPrime = 0;
        System.out.println("Please give a number ");
        int number = scanner.nextInt();
        for (int i = number - 1; i > 2; i--) {
            if (isPrime(i)) {
                minPrime = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int i = number + 1; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
            if (isPrime(i)) {
                maxPrime = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(minPrime);
        System.out.println(maxPrime);
    }

    static boolean isPrime(int n) {
        if (n < 2)
            return false;
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Okay I follow that. If I am right the .Max Value would only print the upper prime

Comment: Yes it is so. For 24 the two numbers are 23 and 29, for 30 the two numbers are 29 and 31.

Comment: Is my answer true, I couldn't understand?

Comment: oh no man i didnt mean that! I meant my previous comment was stupid. Your totally right and I respect you and thank you greatly.

Comment: I an glad to help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a "cached" list of first 100/1000/10000 prime numbers and if input of user is within this range you just have to find two numbers which are closest to user input.

Then you can use something like (with some ifs to sort out cases of user input at beginning/end of list)

```
    for(int i=0;i<cache.size();i++){
        if(userNumber<cache.get(i)){
            indexOfSmallerPrimeNumber = i;
        }
    }
    int smallerPrimeNumber = cache.get(indexOfSmallerPrimeNumber);
    int biggerPrimeNumber = cache.get(indexOfSmallerPrimeNumber+1);
```

When user will input numbers bigger than your cache then you'll have compute next numbers (which may be time consuming for big numbers). You can use for this purpose [sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: It is supposed to test for all. i thought of that as well

Comment: Then you have to use some algorithm for prime numbers generation. For example Erathosthenes sieve.

Comment: Okay so lets say I go with your plan. The difficult part I am having trouble with is determining which numbers are closes to it.

Comment: why are you downing all  my question? I just thought id ask because I am confused and that is what this site is for.

Answer (score 0):

There are several Possibilities to calculate Prime Numbers. E.g. sieve of Eratosthenes or sieve of Atkin

Comment: thats not the issue as much as testing to see what two primes are closest to the value

Comment: simply going the sieve upwards and downwards until you find a prime?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you...

You can customize it as per your need. It worked perfectly while my testing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Prime {
    static boolean isPrime(int val)
    {
        for(int i=val/2;i>1;i--)
        {
            if(val%i==0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number:");
        int num=input.nextInt();
        for(int i=num-1;i>2;i--)
        {
            if(isPrime(i))
            {
                System.out.println("First prime no.: "+i);
                break;
            }
        }
        for(int i=num+1;;i++)
        {
            if(isPrime(i))
            {
                System.out.println("Second prime no.: "+i);
                break;
            }
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can halve the search time by stepping two and ensuring that you only test odd numbers for primality.  If the number given is odd, start the search at the number and step 2.  If the number is even start the searches at n+1 and n-1 and step 2.  It is easy enough to pick off 2 if it is one of the answers.

Comment: @rossum yes, you are right. This will halve the search time.